# Crypto-pouch not encrypting documents for remote CouchDB

Tags: encryption, ionic2, pouchdb

I am trying to use crypto-pouch to encrypt PouchDB and CouchDB documents in my ionic 2 App.

In the crypto-pouch documentation it says "If you replicate to another database, it will decrypt before sending it to the external one. So make sure that one also has a password set as well if you want it encrypted too.". This is what I am trying to do in my code which looks like this:

```js
  init(localDBName, remoteDBName)
  {
    this._DB = new PouchDB(localDBName);

    PouchDB.plugin(CryptoPouch);
    this._DB.crypto('a password');

    this.remote = remoteDBName;    

    console.log('Data: init(): PouchDB database opened for localDBName = ' + localDBName + ' : ' + this._DB + ', remoteDBName = ' + this.remote);

    // Insert the url for the CouchDB server into the remoteDBName 
    var realRemoteDB = this.remote.replace("localhost:5984", COUCHDB_SERVER_URL);

    console.log('Data: init(): remoteDB path being used is: ' + realRemoteDB);


    this._remoteDB = new PouchDB(realRemoteDB);
    this._remoteDB.crypto('a password');


    let options = {
      live: true,
      retry: true,
      continuous: true
    };

    return this._DB.sync(realRemoteDB) //No options here -> One time sync
      .on('complete', (info) => {
        console.log('Data: init(): first one time sync has completed about to do live syncing now');
        this.events.publish('SYNC_FINISHED', true); // Let login know we have synced the data
        return this._DB.sync(realRemoteDB, options) //Continous sync with options
          .on('complete', (info) => {
            console.log('***** DATA: init() Complete: Handling syncing complete');
            console.dir(info);
          })
          .on('change', (info) => {
            console.log('***** DATA: init() Change: Handling syncing change');
            console.dir(info);
          })
          .on('paused', (info) => {
            console.log('***** DATA: init() Paused: Handling syncing pause');
            console.dir(info);
          })
          .on('active', (info) => {
            console.log('***** DATA: init() Active: Handling syncing resumption');
            console.dir(info);
          })
          .on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('***** DATA: init() Error: Handling syncing error');
            console.dir(err);
          })
          .on('denied', (err) => {
            console.log('***** DATA: init() Denied: Handling syncing denied');
            console.dir(err);
          });
      });
  }
```

When I look at the documents on the remote CouchDB server using Futon the documents are not encrypted as they should be.